# Connecting to kubernetes cluster using helm go client

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm go client to install the release. The link is 
https://github.com/helm/helm/tree/55193089e67207363e6f448054113b5a36649d74/pkg/helm

What I didn't get , how can I give my kubeconfig file to this go client so that my client can communicate with the kubernetes cluster. I went through documentation but doesn't has the details on the same.

Is there any other way to connect to cluster from helm go client.